# Generate a random byte in Elixir

Tags: elixir

This seems like a simple question, and I might be missing something obvious, but I can't figure out how to make a function in Elixir that returns a random byte. I want something like:

```
def random_byte do
  <<0>>..<<255>> |> Enum.random()
end
```

But you can't make a range with binaries. I could just manually type out a list of all 256, but I was hoping there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean a binary with one byte? You can put `Enum.random(0..255)` inside the `<<>>`:

```
iex(1)> <<Enum.random(0..255)>>
<<181>>
iex(2)> <<Enum.random(0..255)>>
"x"
```

Another way would be to use `:crypto.strong_rand_bytes/1` (*might* be slower but this is also cryptographically secure):

```
iex(3)> :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(1)
<<205>>
iex(4)> :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(1)
"7"
```

Comment: haha, so obvious but I never would have thought of doing that. Thanks!

Comment: More idiomatic Elixir: `(0..255) |> Enum.random() |> <<>>` :)